# Continuity and Differentiability when $x=0$ then $f(0) = 0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Is $f(x)$ continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?
> Is $f(x)$ differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?
> where $$f(x) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \frac{x \cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}, & x \neq 0 \\
> ~~~~~~~~~0~~~~~~~~~~, & \, x = 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right. $$

**My answer** so far:
If $x \neq 0$ then the function f(x) is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} $ $\Rightarrow$ continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.
If $x = 0$ then the function at $0$ could be differentiable if that's not the case then we have to check continuity at $0$.

How do I find out if $f(0)$ is differantiable or continuous?

**My thoughts:**
If you differntiate $0$ you should get $0$ by definition. So it should be differntiable at $x = 0$.
As for continuity I tried to find the limit $x\to0^+$ and limit $x\to0^-$. Which should exist and should be equal if you approach from negative Infinity and postitive infinity.
Using this formula: [Differentiability of real functions of one variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_complex_analysis)

$$\frac{(\frac{x \cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2})-0}{x-0}\Leftrightarrow \frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}$$

$\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ max values and min values are $1$ and $-1$ so we can approx the function
$$\frac{x}{x^3} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x^2}$$
The limit for pos. and neg. $x \to0$ is in both cases $0$ which means $f(x)$ continuous in $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that, by L'Hopital's Rule\begin{align}\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x\sin(x)+\cancel{\cos(x)}-\cancel{\cos(x)}}{2x}\\&=-\frac12\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)\\&=0,\end{align}and therefore, $f$ is continuous at $0$. A similar approach shows that is is actually differentiable at $0$.